# Phonons and radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, radiation, crystals, phonons

I am trying to understand whether this would impact radiation at all, since the Schrodinger's cat joke and first semester quantum mechanics lay pretty heavily into the idea that radiation is quantum under-determinism.

My question is in three parts:

1. is there a relationship between phonons and random photons in a crystal lattice?
2. is there a relationship between random photons (the ambient photons in an environment) and alpha and/or beta radiation?
3. is there a relationship between phonons and alpha and/or beta radiation, assuming the radiative material has been annealed into a crystal lattice...

And, knitting that all together: what is the relationship between heat, vibrations, phonons and photons relative to radiation? (Or is there none at all?)

Comment: Chris, strange questions for someone who studied physics, aren't they?                    „random photon activity can cause decoherence of an entangled system of particles“: Of course, adding energy to an entangled system leads usual to decoherence.      A lot of unsorted questions and it is not clear where to start. Perhaps you would like to edit it and start with just one question? (The +1 was mine because there are interesting points in your questions.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I've edited my question to be more precise.  Any properties I am composing which I am unsure about at an absolute level are marked "please advise"

Comment: „Radiation output increases as more radiation occurs -- we know this. That is why we use control rods to absorb radiation.“ Radiation increases due to the number of neutrons that get produced during nuclear fission. The rods we put in to absorb neutrons.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler thanks, I added more to that proposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does radiation respond to systematic variation of energy and structure in the solid material? (from the comments)

Radiation consists of quanta of energy, called photons. (This is indisputable, as there is no known method of generating EM radiation other than the emission of photons.)
The emission happens due to the relaxation of electrons from higher energetic levels or from the acceleration of moving electrons. How the inverse process happens?

The absorption is the inverse process. An electron interacts with am incoming photon. The photon can’t be scattered with 100%, that is impossible because a photon carries a moment.

Some of the absorption processes are

- a very week interaction: the photons go through glass (But not 100%. Take a lot of glas and the view though the class will be a bit shifted to green)
- Re-emission with very the same frequency / wavelength: a mirror
- Absorption to 100%: Black body

The last is interesting. Inside the black body the photons get dissipated to a lot of frequencies. This happens also due to phonon vibrations.

In between all of these processes is our real world.

Comment: hey thanks for coaching me on this.  I'll pare it down and re submit.